# Adding weather information to QGIS atlas composer

Tags: qgis, atlas, weather

I'd like to add a tabular weather forecast with climatic variables like temperature, wind, and chance of precipitation to my QGIS atlas composer.  Does anyone have suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a [HTML Frame](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_html_frame.html#figure-composer-html). This way you can master the way things are displayed and you can have an updated image or data based on internet or a server broadcasting those informations.

The button is on the insert objects toolbar in QGIS or you can go through the layout menu/insert html frame.

For HTML code, have a look  below for an working example of HTML code you could insert (from **[OpenWeathermap](https://openweathermap.org/current)** - free for reasonable number of query on the API)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="weather, world, openweathermap, weather, layer" />
  <meta name="description" content="A layer with current weather conditions in cities for world wide" />
  <meta name="domain" content="openweathermap.org" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/A72E43C7-AA15-E24F-ADA1-902DA2479692/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script></head>
<body>
  <div style="font-size: medium; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 0px;">London</div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 130px;">
    <div style="display: block; clear: left;">
      <div style="float: left;" title="Titel">
        <img height="45" width="45" style="border: medium none; width: 45px; height: 45px; background: url(&quot;http://openweathermap.org/img/w/50d.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;" alt="title" src="http://openweathermap.org/images/transparent.png"/>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left;">
        <div style="display: block; clear: left; font-size: medium; font-weight: bold; padding: 0pt 3pt;" title="Current Temperature">7°C</div>
        <div style="display: block; width: 85px; overflow: visible;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: left; font-size: small;">Clouds: 90%</div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: left; color: gray; font-size: x-small;" >Humidity: 81%</div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: left; color: gray; font-size: x-small;" >Wind: 4.6 m/s</div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: left; color: gray; font-size: x-small;" >Pressure: 1012hpa</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: block; clear: left; color: gray; font-size: x-small;">
    <a href="http://openweathermap.org/city/2643743?utm_source=openweathermap&utm_medium=widget&utm_campaign=html_old" target="_blank">More..</a>
  </div>
  <script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', 'UA-31601618-9', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML object is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!